# wtform popup in some cases

Tags: python, flask

I want this popup will show if I make a wrong choice (will defined in the back), and also if the query length is less than 5.
[image]

Some code stuff bellow:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    airport_src = SelectField('AirPort Source', choices=AIR_PORTS_LIST, validators=[DataRequired()])
    airport_dst = SelectField('AirPort Destination', choices=AIR_PORTS_LIST, validators=[DataRequired()])
    query = StringField('query', validators=[InputRequired()])
```

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}

{{ form.airport_src(placeholder='Make Your Choice') }}
{{ form.airport_dst(placeholder='Make Your Choice') }}
{{ form.query}}

<input type="submit" value="Login">
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define length in class as validators :

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):    
    query = StringField('query', validators=[InputRequired(),Length(min=5, max=40)])
```

HTML can be like to handle the errors :

```
{{ form.query.label }}<br>
{{ form.query(size=120) }}<br>
{% for error in form.query.errors %}
<span style="color: black;">[{{ error }}]</span>
{% endfor %}
```